# Tags/Flags in dynamodb items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, tags

I need to create items that maybe have multiple tags, and I want to query them given those flags.
I know mongodb can create this type of indexes if I set an index on a list of keyvalue objects [as described in here](https://www.baeldung.com/mongodb-tagging).

Just now, I need a similar feature in dynamodb. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to index based on nested attributes such as `list` or `map`. One way to overcome this is to create an item per tag.

| PK | SK | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user123 | tagA | someinfo |
| user123 | tagB | someinfo |
| user123 | tagZ | someinfo |

Comment: And I want to sort item with timestamp? tagA#TIMESTAMP in Sk? If i want to filter more than one tag, so I must create two queries and sort again in application layer. Right?

Comment: That's correct.